# Can I update setting of beacon with android estimote app

Tags: android, estimote

I have changed beacon configurations using estimote cloud app.I need update the beacons with the new configuration.For that I used Estimote android app.
I can able to change the beacon configuration using the android app interface.But I couldn't able to configure beacons with the configuration in the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

When you change Estimote Beacons' settings via the Estimote Cloud, the next step is to open the Estimote app, log in, and come in range of the beacons so that the app can propagate the new settings.

At this time, this work only in the Estimote **iOS** app though.

With the Android app, you still need to configure your beacons in-app, by connecting to them one by one.